# qt webview shows no https site

Tags: qt, https

I have a device with linux and I build the system with yocto. I use Qt as a webbrowser and it works for http sites. But when I want to show a https site I got a blank white site. It shows no error messages and also openssl is built and linked (otherwise i would get error messages?!). The folling code shows how i call the WebEngineView in a shell file.

```c
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.2

Window {
    width: 720
    height: 1280
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://wiki.selfhtml.org/"
    }
}
```

Does somebody knows any tipp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QWebView, how to access https protocol WebPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895522/qwebview-how-to-access-https-protocol-webpage)

Comment: When openssl is not linked to QT there must be another error message or? I got no error message at all I only see a white page.

Comment: did you build it with https support?